# Show / Hide DIVs with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, hide, show

i'm new in HTML and JavaScript and I am having a little problem
I have 3 DIVs

```
<div id="div1"> I'm div1 </div>
<div id="div2"> I'm div2 </div>
<div id="div3"> I'm div3 </div>
```

and I have 3 buttons and each one of them enables the corresponding DIV and disables the others to show only 1 DIV at a time

```
<input type="button" name="Showdiv1" value="Show Div 1" onclick="showDiv1()" />
<input type="button" name="Showdiv2" value="Show Div 2" onclick="showDiv2()" />
<input type="button" name="Showdiv3" value="Show Div 3" onclick="showDiv3()" />
```

I've searched multiple solutions and they only show how to enable, and I don't know why, I can't disable them.

Comment: You should probably show your efforts (the `showDiv` functions) so people can let you know where you went wrong and help you improve.

Comment: Yes and you'll probably need to explain what you mean by disable/enable a div. Are you hiding them from view?

Comment: Are you want to hide others 2 divs or something else?

Comment: I've a menu on the left side with categories. At the beggining the center is blank, and when i select a category i want to show a table or text in the center of the screen, and when i select another category, it show's up another element in the center, removing the previous one

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [visibility options](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_visibility.asp). In short in your functions you should call `getElementById`(for the if of the div you want to modify) and than change the visibility property of the style of the found element to `hidden`(to hide the element) or `visible`(to show it).

Answer (score 0):

> To Just Hide the Div - and if you want to occupy the Div space

```
function Hide()
{
document.getElementById('div1').style.visibility="hidden";
}
```

> To Hide and remove the occupied space of the Div element

```
    function Hide()
    {
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display="none";
    }
```

Comment: why not `document.getElementById(...).style.display='none'`

Comment: visibility="none" ! it should be display="none".

Answer (score 0):

```
function showDiv1(){
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('div3').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple version of show/hide
**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" name="Showdiv1" value="div1" />
<input type="button" name="Showdiv2" value="div2" />
<input type="button" name="Showdiv3" value="div3" />
<div id="div1">I'm div1</div>
<div id="div2">I'm div2</div>
<div id="div3">I'm div3</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('input[type="button"]').on('click', function () {
    var div = "#" + $(this).val();
    $('div').hide()
    $(div).show()
})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RvhZ8/)

---

**Updates:** Since you mentioned in pure js here is approach

```
<input type="button" name="Showdiv1" value="div1" onclick="showDiv(this)" />
<input type="button" name="Showdiv2" value="div2" onclick="showDiv(this)" />
<input type="button" name="Showdiv3" value="div3" onclick="showDiv(this)" />
<div id="div1">I'm div1</div>
<div id="div2">I'm div2</div>
<div id="div3">I'm div3</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function showDiv(that) {
    var len = document.getElementsByTagName('div').length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('div')[i].style.display = "none";
    }
var val =  that.value;
 document.getElementById(val).style.display = "block";
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RvhZ8/1/)

Comment: @smerny Just to give a hint that jQuery has a easy approach.  Here is a pure js approach fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RvhZ8/1/

Comment: OP here, i don't know very well, how jquery works, but to test that example do i just do <script> jquery here </script>. i don't need to do anything else to make jquery works?

Comment: @Elsendion for jquery you need to a script file like `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could do this, a step in reducing repeated code would be something like this:

```
<div id=div1> I'm div1 </div>
<div id=div2> I'm div2 </div>
<div id=div3> I'm div3 </div>
<input type="button" name="Showdiv1" value="Show Div 1" onclick="showDiv('1')" />
<input type="button" name="Showdiv2" value="Show Div 2" onclick="showDiv('2')" />
<input type="button" name="Showdiv3" value="Show Div 3" onclick="showDiv('3')" />
```

JS:

```
function showDiv(num) {
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('div2').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('div3').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('div'+num).style.display='block'
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5T8Uj/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution with pure js:

```
<div id=div1> I'm div1 </div>
<div id=div2> I'm div2 </div>
<div id=div3> I'm div3 </div>


<input type="button" name="Showdiv1" value="Show Div 1" onclick="showDiv('div1')" />
<input type="button" name="Showdiv2" value="Show Div 2" onclick="showDiv('div2')" />
<input type="button" name="Showdiv3" value="Show Div 3" onclick="showDiv('div3')" />

<script>
function showDiv(id) {
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");

  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      divs[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  var divToShow = document.getElementById(id);
  divToShow.style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LMKKL/1/)

Comment: any way i can start the divs disabled?